# sum all cells having a not empty cell on the right

Tags: google-spreadsheets

```
  |A|B
 --------------
 1|1|some text|
 2|2|         | 
 3|5|other    |
```

How I can sum column A, including only cells having not empty values in their right neighbour cells(B)?

In this example I would expect result to be `6`, because it should only sum `A1` with `A3` ignoring `A2`, because `B2` is empty.

Played around with `SUMIF` but can't manage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=SUMIF(B1:B3,"<>",A1:A3)`